# UICollectionViewCell not showing images picked from UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Can somebody please see any errors here that are preventing the cell "photoInTheCellnow" to show UIImage values from image Picker

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import PhotosUI

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var photosInTheCellNow = [UIImage]()
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func openLibrary(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

        switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
        case .authorized: print("Access is granted by user")
        case .notDetermined:
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (newStatus) in print("status is \(newStatus)"); if newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized { print("success") } })
        case .restricted: print("User do not have access to photo album.")
        case .denied: print("User has denied the permission.")  
        }

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self


        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

            let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage

            photosInTheCellNow.append(image)
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return photosInTheCellNow.count
        }


        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotosCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotosCollectionViewCell

            return cell
        }

        func register(_ cellClass: PhotosCollectionViewCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String) { }
   }
}
```

This is the custom cell class

```
import UIKit

class PhotosCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good question to me, I don't think the down vote was justified. It's a basic question (and that's totally okay!) but it has all the important parts. A clear code example, explanation of the issue, and a explanation of the desired outcome (though it's implied, in this case).

Comment: To add to @Alexander's point, while a single downvote may be (arguably) not justified, we do not get into the business of removing them. Consider isolated downvotes like a rainy day - they are a trifling inconvenience, but just go about your day. There is no obligation on voters to explain their votes - they are anonymous as a matter of long-standing policy. If you make some good posts here, you will soon earn more up than down.

Comment: @halfer And the system even accounts for that. Question downvotes give 5 rep, whereas downvotes only lose 2 reps. So all `n` of your questions can 50% upvoted, 50% downvoted (leading to a net 0 score), and you would still have `n` reputation

Comment: The other feedback on this post is that the code was pasted into it without any formatting, and it had to be repaired by a volunteer editor. I would imagine that was the reason for the downvote, and although that is entirely a matter of opinion, one can presume that the voter felt that it was justified. I recommend the preview pane is used before submitting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @RaziTiwana, you need to assign the image to your collection view cell in `cellForItemAt:indexPath`.

```
cell.imageView.image =  photosInTheCellNow[indexPath.row]
```

You also need to update the `collectionView` once you have picked the image. You added the image to your `photosInTheCellNow` property, but you haven't let the `collectionView` know the data source changed. You can either reload the entire `collectionView` by calling `collectionView.reloadData()` or just insert the last row as shown here.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
       let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage

       photosInTheCellNow.append(image)
       let indexPath = IndexPath(item: photosInTheCellNow.count-1, section: 0)
       collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
       picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotosCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotosCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView.image =  photosInTheCellNow[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Not working still. I still have this error   :Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled